# Save checkboxes value into another checkbox field

Tags: nodes, forms

I'd like to save the value of a checkboxes field which is link to a product once I save my content type.

I've created the code needed to create the product and the node. When the node is in creation mode everything appear as it should and my node get's save, the product created but I struggle to save the value into the field field_permission that I've added to the product type.

Permission field.

Label: Permissions
Machine Name: field_permission
Field Type: List(text)
Widget: Check boxes/radio buttons

The values inside this field are:

permission1|Permission1
permission2|Permission2
permission3|Permission3

I've selected the number of value to 3. I got my check-boxes field created. Great !

Then, I've created a content type and alter form to save a custom node. I had this form element which appear on the form.

```
    $options = array(
      permission1|Permission1
      permission2|Permission2
      permission3|Permission3
    );


    $form['permission'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#options' => $options,
      '#title' => t('Select permissions:'),
    );
```

Then when I save the new node using a custom submit, I create a product and it works fine, 
But:

I want to save the value selected inside $form[permission] and copy those values to the field_permission I've create onto the product type. I've read that I have to use the wrapper and call the newly created product. Fine. It works but the value aren't still save into my new field. Any idea How to save checkboxes values ?

Thanks.

```
function myform_submit($form, &$form_state){
global $user;

$node = new stdClass();
// Set content type
    $node->type = 'event';
    // Prepare defaults
    node_object_prepare($node);

    $node->title  = $form_state['values']['title'];

    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

    //create path with pathauto
    $path = 'mycontent' . date('YmdHis');
    $node->path = array('alias' => $path);
    $node->uid = $user->uid;


    //create new product type
    $price = $form_state['values']['field_cost']['und'][0]['value'];
    $extra = array(
    'sku' => 'event-' . drupal_hash_base64(microtime()),
    'title' => $node->title,
    'uid' => $node->uid,
    'status' => TRUE,
    );
$reg_id = _create_product('event_product', $price, $extra);

//add permissions value to the product
$product = commerce_product_load($reg_id);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', $product);

$permissions = $form_state['values']['permission'];

    --- HERE IS THE PROBLEM --- How to copy those values ??? 

   foreach ($permissions as $key => $value){
      $wrapper->field_event_permission['#default_value'] = $permissions;
   }

$wrapper->save();

dsm($wrapper->getPropertyInfo());


   //save the field attached to the node
.....
   node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: Since you have a field created with the field API, I don't get why you are using a form element to save its values in that field. You should just let the field API handle it, or create a custom field, if you need something the checkboxes field is not able to achieve.

Comment: Hi kiamlaluno, Thanks for your reply. My problem is not to save the value to the field attached to the node but to save this same value to the field attach to the product.

Comment: In the code you are showing, the 'permission' field is a normal form element created with the FAPI, not the field API. If you are trying to copy the value of a field created with the field API in another similar field, you should show different code.

Comment: Hmmm... That's all that I've done ! But anyway. I realized that I don't need to add the permission to the product. I will just check the permission that are check on the field_permission related to this node and then I will display the Add to cart button only if the user meet the required permission. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Hi Lynx, this issue solved?

Comment: Yeah, more or less a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's solved.

I don't need to add the permission to the product. I just check the permission that are check on the field_permission related to this node and then I display the Add to cart button only if the user meet the required permission.

Thanks